# Can anybody tell me When is the QMenuBar::hovered(QAction*) signal emitted in Apple iMAC system?

Tags: macos, qt, qmenubar

Hi I am working on a Qt GUI project in a iMAC system, in which I have a QMenuBar, I am trying to connect the QMenuBar hovered signal to a slot, the lines are given below

menuBar = PluginLocalManager::getInstance()->getMainWindow()->menuBar();

bool = isConnect=connect(menuBar,SIGNAL(hovered(QAction*)),this,SLOT(slt_menuBarHovered(QAction*)));

qDebug()<<"is menubar connection successfull?: "<< isConnect;

I am getting the bool isConnect as true in qDebug statement, but when I hover over the menubar in the GUI, the signal hovered is not getting emitted and the control is not coming to the SLOT slt_menuBarHovered(QAction*), Does anybody know why is this not happening??

Please Help me, Thank you in advance

Comment: Try to put mouse pointer to a toolbar button or menu item and wait a bit.

Comment: @Riateche Yeah I am trying to put the mouse pointer few seconds, but yet it is not working, the same code works as soon as I move over the menu bar in Qt in windows OS, but why is this case not happening in MAC system, Is there any solution for this I can get??